# primefaces datatable with ajax pagination recreates viewscoped bean

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datatable, pagination, commandbutton

I have a Primefaces datatable with pagination enabled (which I think it uses ajax requests when we move between pages clicking the links of the paginator).

In every row I have a commandbutton for editing the row. The method action of this commandbutton sets a managed bean property to hide the datatable and to show the edit form. I do this by enclosing the datatable in a panelgroup, and the edit form in another one, and setting the rendered attribute of the panelgroups accordingly to the managed bean property.

The managed bean is Viewscoped, and all the requests I have are non-ajax.

When I click the edit commandbutton on a row of the 1st datatable page, everything works ok.

But if I move to another datatable page using the paginator links, and then I click the edit commandbutton on any row of the page, it doesn't work, because the Viewscoped bean is created again (PostConstruct is triggered), and even I can see that the action method of the clicked commandbutton isn't executed.

I think it has to do with the ajax requests of the paginator (I guess).

Anybody knows how to make it work?

Thank you.

I put here the relevant code to understand better the situation.

My view:

```
<ui:composition template="/paginas/plantillas/plantilla.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="contenido">

        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{clienteController.pagina=='LISTA'}">
            <p:messages globalOnly="true" layout="table" closable="true" />
            <p:dataTable id="tablaClientes" value="#{clienteController.clientesLazyList}" var="cli"
                 dblClickSelect="TRUE"
                 selectionMode="single"
                 selection="#{clienteController.cliente}"
                 rowKey="#{cli.id}"
                 paginator="true" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                 currentPageReportTemplate="Total filas: {totalRecords} (mostrando {startRecord} a {endRecord}) (Página {currentPage} de {totalPages})"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} Filas/página: {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 emptyMessage="#{clienteController.msjListaVacia}"
                 lazy="true">

                <p:column ...> ... </p:column>
                      ...
                <p:column headerText="Editar">
                     <h:form>
                     <p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{clienteController.editarAction(cli)}" title="Editar" icon="ui-icon-pencil" />
                     </h:form>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{clienteController.pagina=='FORM'}">
            <p:messages globalOnly="true" layout="table" closable="true" />
            <h:form id="formCliente">
                    ...
                    ...
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

My managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="clienteController")
@ViewScoped
public class ClienteController extends BaseController {

    ...

    public ClienteController() {
        log.info("Constructor ClienteController");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void cargarAtributos() {
        ...
        this.pagina = TipoPagina.LISTA;
        log.info("PostConstruct ClienteController");
    }

    // Getters y Setters
    ...

    // EVENTO: Pulsar el enlace "editar" de la pantalla "lista"
    public String editarAction (Cliente c) {
        log.info("Método editarAction");
        ...
        this.pagina = TipoPagina.FORM;
        return null;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I'm having same issue with Mojarra JSF 2.3.3 and Primefaces 6.2 on a Payara 4.1.2.181.

Answer (score 2):

Pity but there seems to be a problem with view scoped beans and primefaces datatable...but it is not so primefaces related but more JSF staff propably. As many posts have issued, there is a problem with some a method called binding used in Jsf that makes the recreation of the view bean temporarily. i dont thing there is an easy way to bypass it. unless primafaces finds a way with an update in their components when used in view scope.

Comment: I've changed the scope of the bean to SessionScoped and the problem still remains. If I edit a row of the 1st page, it works. But if I interact with the primefaces datatable (click on sort column, on a page link, etc), then the commandbutton of the edit column doesn't work, it recreates the bean. I think it's primefaces issue, beacuse I did this pagination manually before in another project, with plain JSF tags (h prefix) and it worked well. Please anyone knows why this happen? Thank you.

Comment: @choquero70 have you considered upgrading PF to latest stable? If the bug still persists, please open a ticket at github.